# Test if substring is a number and if it is larger than another number in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a json file that has a string as the pubDate.  The pubDate could be 2010 or 2010 Mar or 2010/1/1 or Blank or Not available.  What I have is

```
var res = pubDate.substr(0, 4);
var i = parseInt(res, 10);
if (!isNaN(i)) {                    
    if (i > 2010) {
        //do work
    }
}
```

This works but I'd love to have some cleaner code where I might be able to do it in one or two lines of code.  This this possible?

Comment: I'm thinking this question may be better for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), as you're trying to improve already-working code rather than solve an issue.

Comment: parseInt naturally throws an exception if it cant parse If i am correct.  So, you could also wrap the content with a try-catch and just continue.  `try {var i = parseInt(res, 10); if (i> 2010){ /* do work */}}catch(exception){ /* NAN */ }`

Comment: @Fallenreaper `parseInt("abc")` does not throw an exception, it returns `NaN`.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry you are totally right.  I was thinking of a different language.  Dang it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If `i` is `NaN`, `i > 2010` will be false, so the `isNaN` check is not neccessary.

2) ParseInt ignores suffix characters, so you don't have to substr:

```
const year = parseInt(pubDate);
if(year > 2010) {
  //...
 }
```

Comment: Up vote from me, very slick. That said, I wonder if including the redundant `isNaN` is worth the improved readability? Or is it assumed that others should know `NaN > n == false`? Not a criticism by any means, just wondering what your opinion would be in that regard.

Comment: @tyler depends on your teammates. I would probably add a comment like `/* Also excludes years that cannot be parsed, as NaN always fails in a comparison */`

Comment: Good point. That said, I was entirely unaware of your second point above. I'd always though that the unary `+` operator and `parseInt()` were interchangeable, however in this case they are not. Thanks for that!

Comment: @tyler actually one of the inconsistencies i always forget, this time I chose the right one...

Comment: That what I like about this site, there is always a better solution. It's clean and simple and does the job.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty messy situation it sounds like, short of collapsing some of those lines I don't think you have much of an option. By collapsing some of the lines I mean literally:

```
var i = parseInt((pubDate.substr(0, 4), 10);
if (!isNan(i) && i > 2010) {
    // do work
}
```

But this is assuming you don't need "res" for something later, which looks like you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe two lines of code. Maybe not cleaner code.

```
var i = (!isNaN(parseInt(pubDate.substr(0, 4))))?parseInt(pubDate.substr(0, 4)):0;
if( i > 2010 ){
    //do work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking for decimal specific you could remove the 10. More information about this on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

```
var i = parseInt(pubDate.substr(0, 4));
if (!isNaN(i) && i > 2010) { 
     //do work
}
```